# js getContext stops further code from executing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a working `getContext` in my JavaScript code, but for some reason nothing is executed after this method. Here, I added two alerts and only one of them runs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <canvas id="myCanvas"
    width="0"
    height="0"
    style="border:5px solid #888888; fill: solid #DDDDDD;"
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>

    <script>
        // basic vars
        var squareDim = 25;
        var screenWidth = 10;
        var screenHeight = 20;
        // setting up the canvas
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        canvas.width = screenWidth * squareDim;
        canvas.height = screenHeight * squareDim;
        alert(1)
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        alert(2);

        // draw a single square
        function putSquare(color, x, y) {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(x * squareDim, y * squareDim, squareDim, squareDim);
        }

        for (i=0; i<screenHeight; i++) {
            putSquare("#FF0000", i, 0);
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Does anyone have an idea where did I screw up?

Comment: Oops, forgot the semicolon after the first alert. Didn't change anything though (surprise!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `c.getContext(...)`, you have no `c` variable declared - you need to call this on `canvas` instead:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

---

In future you can debug things like this in your browser's JavaScript console. In your JavaScript console, you'll see that your code here is throwing the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: `c` is not defined

See: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked, I just forgot to change this `c` to `canvas`.
Note to self: get used to checking the console.